# IntelliJ disable Jalopy for a specific project

Tags: intellij-14, jalopy, intellij-15

How can I disable Jalopy for a specific project in IntelliJ Idea 14 or 15?

It seems that he is not so friend with Java8, but all other projects are in Java7. So, I need to selectively disable Jalopy. Or maybe It would be nice to enable it only for specific projects.

Can someone provide a kind of tutorial. An answer suggested to use aliases, but I would like to see how.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a exclusion as below. use a unique folder name as below
[image]

or add it in to the jalopy.xml

```
<exclusions>**/git-repo/**</exclusions>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can configure jalopy by alias, simply do not include your project in the alias if you don't want to run the Jalopy configuration for that project/module.